# ffmpeg stream rejected by youtube because it's too slow

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming, youtube-data-api

I have an app that sends WebM video to a socket in my server, the socket then executes ffmpeg to transform the video to flv and send it to a youtube rtmp ingester.

Thing is, youtube rejects the stream, saying that the broadcast status is incorrect, no matter what I do.

In my naivette I initially tried to stream 1080p and 720p, that failed, so I went down, assuming that that might help me with the bitrate issue... It did not.

The error that Youtube gives me is in spanish but it basically says that the stream is too slow and I should lower resolution or bitrate(I'm already @ 240p and it's not working).

Edit: Here's the error, translated:

> Main broadcast:
>   YouTube is not receiving enough video to guarantee a fluid broadcast. Buffering will occur.
>
> Main Broadcast: We are not receiving video data at a fast enough speed. Your audience may experience buffering. Make sure that your connection is fast enough o consider using a lower bitrate.

Here is my call to ffmpeg thus far (language is node.js if that matters.):

```
const ffmpeg = child_process.spawn('ffmpeg', [

    '-f', 'lavfi', '-i', 'anullsrc',

    //    '-re', // I was told i shouldnt use this parameter. i dont know, honestly.



    // FFmpeg will read input video from STDIN
    '-i', '-',

    // Because we're using a generated audio source which never ends,
    // specify that we'll stop at end of other input.  Remove this line if you
    // send audio from the browser.
    '-shortest',

    '-vcodec', 'libx264',

    '-acodec', 'aac',

    //ffmpeg
    //-re -loop 1
    //-framerate 2 -i test1.jpg -i https://xxxxxxxxxxx:8443/live.ogg
    //-c:a aac
    //-s 2560x1440
    //-ab 128k -vcodec libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -maxrate 2048k -bufsize 2048k
    //'-framerate', '30',
    '-r', '24',
    //'-s', '2560x1440',


    '-force_key_frames','expr:gte(t\,n_forced/2)',

    '-preset', 'ultrafast',
    '-pix_fmt', 'yuv420p',
    '-s', '426x240',
    '-crf', '23',
    '-bf', '2',
    '-q:a', '1',
    '-ac', '2',
    '-ar','48000',
    '-use_editlist','0',
    '-movflags','+faststart',
    //  '-ab', '128k',
    '-g', '48',

    //'-minrate', '1500k',
    '-minrate', '1000k',
    '-maxrate', '2000k',

    '-bufsize', '2000k',/*
    '-g', '30',*/
    //'-keyint_min', '30',
    //'-t', '30',

    ////
    '-deadline', 'realtime',
    '-cpu-used','-16',

    '-tune', 'zerolatency',

    '-threads', '4',

    //-g 2 -strict experimental -f flv rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/xxxxxxxxxxxxx


    // FLV is the container format used in conjunction with RTMP
    '-f', 'flv',



    // The output RTMP URL.
    // For debugging, you could set this to a filename like 'test.flv', and play
    // the resulting file with VLC.  Please also read the security considerations
    // later on in this tutorial.
    rtmpUrl
]);
```

Edit: input is fed via stdin whenever the socket receives data.

In my completely uneducated opinion, the "-deadline realtime" & the "-tune zerolatency" parts seemed to help somewhat but not enough to get me streamin'.

Here is some of the output of ffmpeg:

```
FFmpeg STDERR: frame=   35 fps=3.1 q=23.0 size=     104kB time=00:00:08.44 bitrate= 100.4kbits/s dup=0 drop=3 speed=0.76x    
FFmpeg STDERR: frame=   35 fps=3.0 q=23.0 size=     104kB time=00:00:08.44 bitrate= 100.4kbits/s dup=0 drop=3 speed=0.726x    
FFmpeg STDERR: frame=   35 fps=2.9 q=23.0 size=     104kB time=00:00:08.44 bitrate= 100.4kbits/s dup=0 drop=3 speed=0.696x    
FFmpeg STDERR: frame=   36 fps=2.8 q=23.0 size=     109kB time=00:00:09.45 bitrate=  94.6kbits/s dup=0 drop=3 speed=0.747x    
FFmpeg STDERR: frame=   36 fps=2.7 q=23.0 size=     109kB time=00:00:09.45 bitrate=  94.6kbits/s dup=0 drop=3 speed=0.719x    
FFmpeg STDERR: frame=   38 fps=2.8 q=23.0 size=     121kB time=00:00:11.45 bitrate=  86.7kbits/s dup=0 drop=3 speed=0.839x
```

This is extremely frustrating.

Please, guys, any guidance is good. what is it that I should be maximizing or minimizing? how do I do that? I honestly do not care about everything else going to hell (for example the video freezing or being severely pixelated at times) I just care about being able to stream

Thank you in advance for anything that might help me!

UPDATE: I created a new broadcast, with variable bitrate, I broadcasted to it, it was at "status:optimal" for a few seconds then fps and speed went down and the stream went back to "status: incorrect"

Comment: `speed=0.839x` --> this should remain steady at 1x ideally.

Comment: How should I go about this? Btw I did an experiment, I went down to 6 FPS, speed is at ~6x in the beginning, then goes down, and it stabilizes at around 1x. Status switched to "Accept" (but still no video). I will keep updating this. Please feel free to make suggestions since I've never done this so I'm completely clueless.

Comment: with the 6 FPS @ 240p it "works" now. Meaning that it freezes in random frames, then unfreezes and sends bursts of frames suddenly. But at least It's broadcasting.

Comment: I cannot replicate this again, it was a fluke, apparently.